# dynamically get properties using method in javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

If I create a class `SONG()`, and define many properties, how can i create a method that will use an argument passed through and get that property?

```
function SONG(i) {

    /* properties */
    this.title      = results.title[i];
    this.artist     = results.artist[i];
    this.album      = results.album[i];
    this.info       = results.info[i];

    /* methods */
    this.getstuff = function(stuff){
        console.log(this.stuff); // doesn't work
    }
}

var song1 = new SONG(1);

song1.getstuff(title);  
// how can I have this dynamically 'get' the property passed through as an argument?
```

any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is because your inner `this.stuff` is referring to the annon function that it's inside of.

Comment: Note that `song1.getstuff(title);` tries to pass the **variable** `title` (which is not defined) to `getstuff`.

Comment: @ryan: Since the object does not have a property `stuff`, `this.stuff` is simply `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/RPsgW/))

```
function SONG(i) {
    /* properties */
    this.title      = "My Title";
    this.artist     = "My Artist";
    /* methods */
    this.getstuff = function(stuff){
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(stuff))
            return this[stuff];
        else
            return null;
    }
}

var song1 = new SONG(1);

console.log(song1.getstuff("title"));  
console.log(song1.getstuff("invalid"));
```

But notice here that we are passing in `"title"` as a string. Also, there needs to be a check within `getstuff` to validate that `SONG` indeed has the property that is being requested, hence the check for `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: THANKS! I think i was not passing the argument as a string as you said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use square-bracket notation:

```
this[title]
```

will get the property with the name contained in the title variable.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, not sure where I would put this in. I have `this[title]` in the function

Comment: Where is your function code ?

Comment: nevermind, this worked! I think i was not passing the argument as a string. Thanks!